# animate (fadeIn) img src if loaded react #noJQuery

Tags: javascript, html, image, reactjs, src

i`ve have the problem that the img src has a loading time, in the mean time i show a grey background on the img tag as a placeholder.

if the img src is loaded, i want to fade in the img. is it possible to animate something like img src change?

```
<img
                    ref={ref => this.image = ref}
                    src={`someImgUrl`}
                    onError={() => this.image.setAttribute('src', 'someErrorImgUrl')}
                    style={{ width: '66px', height: '66px', backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
>
```

thx 4 ur time

Comment: not exacly the fade effect but you can show a default image till the actual image actually loads.

Answer (score 3):

you have a `load` event on images that fires when the image is loaded, so you could achieve that with it

and here's a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6L1rryud/)

Answer (score 0):

With React you can create an image loader component, something like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const _loaded = {};
class ImageLoader extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    className: "",
    loadingClassName: "loading",
    loadedClassName: "loaded"
  };

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { loaded: _loaded[props.src] };
  }

  onLoad = () => {
    console.log("LOADED");
    _loaded[this.props.src] = true;
    this.setState(() => ({ loaded: true }));
  };

  render() {
    let { className, loadedClassName, loadingClassName, ...props } = this.props;
    className = `${className} ${this.state.loaded
      ? loadedClassName
      : loadingClassName}`;

    return <img {...props} className={className} onLoad={this.onLoad} />;
  }
}

export default ImageLoader;
```

And use it later:

```
<ImageLoader src={src} />
```

Complete example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6ykm7o4lzk